# What percentage of users can't read html emails

Tags: email, statistics, html-email, usage-statistics

I'm looking for an up to date statistics of how many users wont be able to read my messages if I only send an html message.

The reason I want this information, is to know if its worth to do the effort to support both html/plain-text emails.

Thanks :)